# Htmlでinputタグから受けとった値の処理の方法を教えてください。

Tags: python, html, css, flask

プログラミング初心者です。HTMLでinputタグでワードを受け取り、その結果をもとにおすすめの映画を紹介するというサービスを考えています。HTMLでinputタグから入力フォームは作成したのですが、ここからどのように進めればいいかわかりません。

web開発の手順では、HTML・CSSを作成してからPythonなどのバックエンドの作り方を紹介されていますが、このような仕組みの場合、入力フォーム作成後、バックエンドで入力された値を受け取り、処理をする仕組みを作るべきでしょうか？

プログラミング初心者のため、どのように検索すればいいかわからず質問させて頂きました。
抽象的な質問になってしまい申し訳ありませんがよろしくお願いします。

Comment: たしか今年の5月くらいにhtml内のタグとしてpython（まだ実装が不完全なので一部のライブラリのみだが）実装されてませんでしたでしょうか？Pythonじゃないと処理できないのであれば、「htmlにpythonを埋め込む」とかで記事を見つけられると思います。もしhtmlに対して適用済みのライブラリで対応できない場合はウェブサーバー側の設定で「cron設定」などでpythonで作成したプログラムを呼び起こすか、phpの「php コマンドライン 実行」とかで出てくるので起動するとかでしょうか。

Comment: 入力ワードから検索処理を行い、結果を返すだけであればpythonに依存する優先的な理由が薄いかもしれません。その場合は映画リストをデータベースで保持してphpから制御とかでも足りるかもしれません。技術的にpythonでバックエンドを処理するフローをお探しの場合は他の方のコメントお待ちいただけますか。お力になれなくてすみません。

Comment: pythonではありませんが、やりたいことはこんな感じでしょうか [サーバーからのデータ取得](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Fetching_data)

Answer (score 1):

ユーザーからのフォームデータを受け取って何らかの応答を返すプログラムを **CGI** と呼び、Python を含めて色々な言語で記述することが出来ます。

私自身は Python に詳しくないので具体的な回答まではできませんが、例えば「Python form 取得」などのキーワードで検索してみると以下のようなページがヒットするので参考にしてみて下さい。

[PythonでHTMLフォームのデータを受信し表示する](https://qiita.com/maec_lamar/items/42162640cd8819fab663)

Answer (score 0):

このチュートリアルは入力したURLに対してGETリクエストを発行します。
[Chrome拡張の作り方 15 Httpリクエスト](https://youtu.be/SzoFzBYeMrg)
シンプルなプログラムなので理解するのは容易だと思います。
プログラムは以下からダウンロード出来ます。[Chapter15_MV3.zip](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ObJ5qo8vWuYRhcUmTblt8v0DYIEaAH8Q/view?usp=sharing)